# Convert a numerical relative index (=months) to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

Given is a Pandas DataFrame with a numerical index representing the relative number of months:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'], index=np.arange(1,100))
df

    A   B
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
...
```

How can the index be converted to a DateTimeIndex by specifying a *start date* (e.g., 2018-11-01)?

```
magic_function(df, start='2018-11-01', delta='month')

           A  B
2018-11-01 NaN NaN
2018-12-01 NaN NaN
2019-01-01 NaN NaN
...
```

I would favor a general solution that also works with arbitrary deltas, e.g. daily or yearly series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html)

```
idx=pd.date_range(start='2018-11-01',periods =len(df),freq='MS')
df.index=idx
```

Comment: [Here is a list of frequencies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) (months, hours, days, years, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with Pandas, but with plain `datetime` can't you just do this?

`import datetime
start=datetime.date(2018,1,1)
months = 15
adjusted = start.replace(year=start.year + int(months/12), month=months%12)`